# Use JS appendChild on a GWT Element

Tags: javascript, gwt, native, jsni

I'm having a surprising issue: I've created a method to underline it:

```
protected native String jsAppendChild(Element item)/*-{
    var div = $doc.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "hey do you see me";
    item.appendChild(div);
}-*/;
```

calling this method on a GWT Element doesn't add the element to the DOM!?

Any explanations?

Comment: How are calling this method? What `Element` is here? Please provide some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a simple typo:

```
div.innerHtml = "hey do you see me";
```

should be

```
div.innerHTML = "hey do you see me";
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: I know, I'm just show casing the problem. What I'm doing can't be done in GWT. It works in native code but gets stuck at this point (that's why I highlighted the issue only)

Comment: @ZiedHamdi Did you make sure `item` is attached to the DOM?

Comment: Yes Baz, it's attached and the document is completely loaded. 
Just to add some pepper to the use case, I'm attemping to add this element in an internal iFrame : so I'm creating the element with $doc byt I'm appending it to an inner iFrame.
I have to test a lot of cases it seams

Comment: To be completely specific, it's not a div but an image, and it's created inside a js as follows: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwtupload/O1cjVxK-HTQ

So if I have to do back and forth native calls, it should be justified

Comment: thanks, for the edit. but it still doesn't solve the issue. I'll edit the question to have the right syntax: the issue is not in the inner html but in the fact that the div is not appended

Comment: @ZiedHamdi Well, I tried it and it works just fine by just replacing that line...

Comment: Right! I tried it now in the same document, it works. So I'll have to edit a new question for why it doesn't get added inside an iFrame :)

Answer (score 0):

@Baz is right, if you are familiar with jQuery, you can use GQuery as well:

```
GQuery.$(item).append("<div>Ey do you see me?</div>");
```

Comment: My issue is not "how to add a div?" it is "how to use js appendChild on a Gwt Element". Thankss but I know it works in pure gwt or gquery :)
I have this need in a context where I can't use GWT or gQuery

Comment: You are totally right, sorry. Let me think about it.

Comment: Yes thanks :) (I'll have to repost a question for my real issue that doesn't use innerHTML at all, but thanks for the answer )